# Flask and WTForms - how FlaskForm works?

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms

I am learning Flask and I have trouble understanding FlaskForm from Flask-WTF.
This example is from the book *Flask Web Development: Developing Web Applications with Python, Miguel Grinberg*.
Code below.

hello.py

```
class NameForm(FlaskForm):
    name = StringField('What is your name?', validators=[DataRequired()])
    submit = SubmitField('Submit')
 
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    name = None
    form = NameForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        name = form.name.data
    return render_template('index.html', form=form, name=name)
```

index.html

```
{% import "bootstrap/wtf.html" as wtf %}
{% block page_content %}
<div class="page-header">
    <h1>Hello, {% if name %}{{ name }}{% else %}Stranger{% endif %}!</h1>
</div>
{{ wtf.quick_form(form) }}
{% endblock %}
```

This simple application get name from the user and displays a personalized message.
Suppose I have entered my name and click submit button. How it's possible that entered name is recived from the *form* object (instance of *NameForm*) and send to render

```
name = form.name.data
```

when before this, **new** instance of *NameForm* is assigned to the *form* variable?

```
form = NameForm()
```

Comment: https://github.com/lepture/flask-wtf/blob/c0e42ac78c347d0d26496a8903b854f24f1b3107/flask_wtf/form.py#L27

Answer (score 2):

Without FlaskForm.
You can get the `name` that submitted by user using `Flask.request` like following:

```py
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    name = None
    name = request.form.get('name', None)
```

（you need append `from Flask import request` )

This means any library can get request values through the `Flask.request` object when that  called from handler. And this is why FlaskForm does not need any arguments to get requested values (as long as it is called from a request handler).